# python precision + fft

Tags: python, fft, precision

I have been learning fft, particularly for use in competitive coding contests. I came up with a python implementation after some googling. To test it I created a naive implementation for polynomial multiplication as well.

The code is as follows:

```
from cmath import pi, cos, sin
mod = 100003

def fft(x, inv):
    n = len(x)
    j = 0
    for i in xrange(1, n):
        b = n >> 1
        while j >= b:
            j -= b
            b >>= 1
        j += b
        if j > i:
            x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
    trans_size = 2
    while trans_size <= n:
        w = 1
        ang = [-2 * pi / trans_size, 2 * pi / trans_size][inv]
        wn = complex(cos(ang), sin(ang))
        for t in xrange(trans_size >> 1):
            for trans in xrange(n / trans_size):
                i = trans * trans_size + t
                j = i + (trans_size >> 1)
                a = x[i]
                b = x[j] * w
                x[i] = a + b
                x[j] = a - b
            w *= wn
        trans_size <<= 1

def polymul(x, y):
    lx = len(x)
    ly = len(y)
    lz = 1 << (lx + ly - 1).bit_length()
    x += [0] * (lz - lx)
    y += [0] * (lz - ly)
    fft(x, 0)
    fft(y, 0)
    z = []
    for i in xrange(lz):
        z.append(x[i] * y[i])
    fft(z, 1)
    for i in xrange(lx + ly - 1):
        z[i] = int(z[i].real/lz + 0.5) % mod
    return z[:lx + ly - 1]

def naive_polymul(x, y):
    lx = len(x)
    ly = len(y)
    z = [0 for i in xrange(lx + ly - 1)]
    for i in xrange(lx):
        for j in xrange(ly):
            z[i + j] += x[i] * y[j]
    for i in xrange(lx + ly - 1):
        z[i] %= mod
    return z

from random import randint

N = input()
A = [randint(1, 100000) for i in xrange(N)]
B = [randint(1, 100000) for i in xrange(N)]
C = naive_polymul(A, B)
D = polymul(A, B)
assert(C == D)
```

Now, I give the size of the two polynomials that are randomly generated as input. Up until 4000 it works fine, but at 5000 the assertion fails.

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
4000
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
5000

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fft.py", line 75, in <module>
    assert(C == D)
AssertionError
```

I played around with the code a bit and I am pretty sure that the problem lies in the precision errors due to float values, the values of coefficients are always off by 1. The only way to increase precision I know is Decimal but it significantly slows down the code which is the exact opposite of what I am going for here.

Because of this the question I am testing my code on ( https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/emma-and-sum-of-products ) gives me wrong answer on the larger test cases whereas the C++ submissions (from other users) pass them just fine using your standard long double.

What am I missing here? Would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction to fix this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use [`numpy.fft`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html)?

Comment: Like I said, it is for competitive coding contests. No other libraries are allowed except the default.